# C # MVC how to call the url from jquery

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I have an anchor class below

```
<a class="delete" href="@Url.Action("methodname","controller", new { id= "18"})">delete</a>
```

and an Div class below

```
<div id="confirmation" hidden = "hidden">  <p>Are you sure you want to delete this item?</p>  </div>
```

below is the jquery

// Below will open the div confirmation box once user clicks on delete

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".delete").click(function () {

        $('#confirmation').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
});
```

// I have two buttons continue and cancel, once user clicks on continue I need to have that URl action called with parameters

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#confirmation').dialog({

        autoOpen: false 
        buttons: {
            "Continue": function () {

                //code here
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can  do like this

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
            id: id,
        },
    url: "/Controller/Method",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        window.location.href = "/Controller/Method";
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert(result.responseText);
    },
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, How do you pass the id value from one class to another

Comment: Your method should get the value of id if your method has a parameter of id